# Part of category coming from product structure

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Suppose I have a category $C$ with all finite products. What is an elegant way to describe the wide subcategory $D$ of $C$ that just uses the arrows that "come directly from the product structure of $C$" ?

Here $D$'s arrows consist of identities, projections, and the additional arrows that one can get by forming tuples and composites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $\mathbb L(|C|)$ the free cartesian (i.e. finite product) category on the set of objects of $C$. This is equipped with a functor $|C| \to \mathbb L(|C|)$, where we view the $|C|$ as a discrete category. There is a unique identity-on-objects functor $|C| \to C$, so, by the universal property of $\mathbb L(|C|)$, there is a unique functor $\mathbb L(|C|) \to C$, which identifies the finite product structure in $|C|$. This functor is [essentially surjective on objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+surjective+functor), since $|C| \to C$ is. Abstractly, the functor $\mathbb L(|C|) \to C$ is essentially (up to taking the [full image factorisation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+image)) the $|C|$-sorted finitary [algebraic theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory) underlying the cartesian category $|C|$.